# Как хранить в базе ссылки на файлы сервера?

Tags: sql-server

Сиквел 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаете таблицу с полем типа nvarchar(max) и кладете туда ссылки.

Comment: я просто только начал заниматься базами!! Объясню по проще мой вопрос у меня есть на сервере множество текстовых файлов(pdf, doc и т.д ) мне нужно хранить в базе ссылки на эти файлы!!

Comment: Не понятно, если а базе хранятся файлы это должно быть blob-поля, как можно на них сделать ссылку. Или как они у тебя там в базе хранятся? И что за база данных?

Answer (score 1):

Храните в БД "ссылки" в таком виде, в котором вам будет удобно с ними работать. Допустим у вас сайт simple.com, а файлы лежат в папке files, следовательно ссылка будет на них такая: www.simple.com/files/FileName.txt например. Для подобного случая достаточно в БД хранить всего лишь имена файлов, а все остальное генерировать в коде. Это также сослужит вам службу в будущем при переезде на новый хостинг.